# Deploy GCP Cloud functions to Artifact Registry using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, terraform, continuous-deployment, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to deploy cloud function to artifact registry instead of container registry using Terraform.

I have created an artifact repository in GCP and Using the google-beta provider.
But I am not able to understand where to mention "docker-registry" path(path for artifact registry)

Following in my main tf file's create CF:-
I have added a parameter called docker-repository(this doesn't exist in terraform) based on https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/building#image_registry_options
But looks like this parameter doesn't exist in terraform and is giving me errors.

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "appConfigService" {
  provider              = google-beta
  name                  = local.function_names.appConfigService
  description           = "helloWorld"
  runtime               = var.cf_node_run_time
  available_memory_mb   = var.cf_memory
  source_archive_bucket = local.deployment_bucket
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.appConfigService_archive.name
  entry_point           = "helloWorld"
  service_account_email = var.default_service_account[var.environment]
  trigger_http          = true
  docker-repository     ="<artifact registry path>" //This is wrong

}
```

I am not able to find any documentation on this anywhere.
Please let me know the correct way of deploying Cloud functions to artifact repository using terraform.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that new parameter. I'm sure the Terraform provider are also not up to date.

Comment: docker-registry parameter doesn't exist in terraform, I am looking for equivalent in terraform. If you have deployed to artifact registry via Terraform, please post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, your will need to use Terraform plus Cloud Build to specify the repository to use. You can then use gcloud **--docker-repository** in a Cloud Build step.

This document explains how to integrate Terraform with Cloud Build.

[Managing infrastructure as code with Terraform, Cloud Build, and GitOps](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/managing-infrastructure-as-code)

Comment: Turns out, this is the only way as of now, Unless terraform adds this feature, We can't do much.